# How to select element by index in XPath .net application

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have the following xml received from a web service

```
<GRID xmlns="http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_functions/MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result">
  <DATA>
    <R>
      <D>2645</D>
      <D>HJIT.HRE@RGW.COM</D>
      <D>2019-09-27 10:17:36.0</D>
      <D>114041</D>
      <D>Awaiting Planning</D>
      <D>Work Planned</D>
    </R>
    <R>
      <D>2649</D>
      <D>HJIT.HRE@RGW.COM</D>
      <D>2019-09-27 10:33:24.0</D>
      <D>114043</D>
      <D>Awaiting Release</D>
      <D>Awaiting Planning</D>
    </R>
    <R>
      <D>2652</D>
      <D>HJIT.HRE@RGW.COM</D>
      <D>2019-09-27 10:36:53.0</D>
      <D>114041</D>
      <D>Awaiting Planning</D>
      <D>Work Planned</D>
    </R>
  </DATA>
</GRID>
```

I wrote the following piece of .NET code to extract the R nodes

```
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)Req.GetResponse();

XPathDocument xpResDoc = new XPathDocument(resp.GetResponseStream());
XPathNavigator xpNav = xpResDoc.CreateNavigator();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xpNav.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("g2", "http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_functions/MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result");

XPathNodeIterator xpNIter = xpNav.Select("//g2:R", nsmgr); // I can successfully get the three R elements 

foreach (XPathNavigator nav in xpNIter)
{

    /*
        Now I want to iterate through each R element and use XPATH to select each of the six D nodes by its index position.
        The order of the D nodes are a known dataset and I want to build a comma separated string by concatenating the value of each D node,
        which will later be appended to a CSV file along with a pre-defined header row.
    */

    /* I attempted the following XPATH */

    // XPathNodeIterator xpDi = nav.Select("(//D)[1]"); -- This does not work and yields a null result
}
```

Now I want to iterate through each R element and use XPATH to select each of the six D nodes by its index position. The order of the D nodes are a known dataset and I want to build a comma separated string by concatenating the value of each D node, which will later be appended to a CSV file along with a pre-defined header row.

I didn't want to use anything like LINQ to XML as this is part of read-only data extraction program which needs to be as lite and as performant as possible.

What is the correct way to get the D elements by index with XPATH using the XPathNavigator ?

Comment: Why not create mapping class instead of traversing the nodes?

Comment: did you mean to deserialize to a class ? thought it was not needed since this does not have any front-end UI, its just part of a data pipeline which needs to run on a schedule each hour or so, so need to be lite and simple. does that make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

1. `xpNav.Select("//g2:R", nsmgr)` does not work for the XML shown in your question.

   This expression selects for nodes with local name `R` in the `http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_functions/MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result` namespace -- however in your actual XML none of the nodes are in this namespace.  There's a namespace declaration `xmlns:dstm="http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_functions/MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result"` but it's not the default namespace, so none of the nodes are actually in it, as they aren't using the `dstm:` prefix.

   Instead, you should do `xpNav.Select("//R", nsmgr)` (or better yet `xpNav.Select("/*/DATA/R", nsmgr)`).

   In your question you wrote *I can successfully get the three R elements* so maybe this is a typo in the question.
2. *`nav.Select("(//D)[1]");` -- This does not work and yields a null result.*

   I cannot reproduce this exact problem -- [`XPathNavigator.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.select)never returns `null`.  It will throw an exception on a malformed query, but not return null.

   What I can reproduce is that this always returns **the same result** for every `<R>`, specifically the value of the **first** `<D>` element, `<D>2645</D>`.  Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M9WcF1).

   The problem here is that the recursive descent operator `//D` selects for all nodes named `R` **in the entire document**.  To select only the nodes in the current `<R>` element you need to restrict the scope by prefacing the XPath query with `.`: `nav.Select("(.//D)[1]")` (or better yet, `nav.Select("(./D)[1]")`).

   Incidentally, since you expect 6 child `<D>` nodes of `<R>` it will be more performant to run one single `XPath` query and collect all 6 into a list, rather than running 6 queries for each specific node:

   ```
   var nodes = nav.Select("./D").Cast<XPathNavigator>().ToList();
   ```
3. You indicated that performance is important, but you are using the recursive descent operator `//` which can have bad performance.

   From *[Effective Xml Part 2: How to kill the performance of an app with XPath…](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xmlteam/2011/09/26/effective-xml-part-2-how-to-kill-the-performance-of-an-app-with-xpath/)*:

   > **`//` (descendant-or-self axis)**
   >
   > This is a very common pattern that very often leads to serious performance problems. The way it works is that it flattens the whole subtree (the most common usage I saw is flattening the whole xml document) and then it looks for the specified elements. Now in the .NET Framework there aren’t any specific optimizations for this patterns and using it *is costly*...

   Instead, it's better to specify the path directly.

Pulling all of the above together, your code should look something like:

```
//xpNav and nsmgr set up as in the question
var csvLines = xpNav.Select("/*/DATA/R", nsmgr).Cast<XPathNavigator>()
    .Select(nav => string.Join(",", nav.Select("./D").Cast<XPathNavigator>()))
    .ToList();
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hqTSxy).

Notes:

- If the XML in your question has been incorrectly edited and the nodes `<R>` and `<D>` are really in the `dstm:` namespace after all, add the `g2:` prefix to the node names in the XPath queries like so:

  ```
  var csvLines = xpNav.Select("/*/g2:DATA/g2:R", nsmgr).Cast<XPathNavigator>()
      .Select(nav => string.Join(",", nav.Select("./g2:D", nsmgr).Cast<XPathNavigator>()))
      .ToList();
  ```

  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FkaGgR).
- As an aside, you might want to check your assumption that `XPathDocument` will be more performant than LINQ to XML.  I am not sure this will be the case.

Comment: Thanks some very valuable points you have raised. The XML I have here is a small sample set from a larger document just for illustration purposes and while experimenting I added the dstm: prefix and forgot to take it out later, although the actual document does not have this prefix. I have taken onboard your points 2 and 3 which I think makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

I was on the right path, just needed to use the right method which allows to specify the namespace as seen below:

```
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)Req.GetResponse();

XPathDocument xpResDoc = new XPathDocument(resp.GetResponseStream());
XPathNavigator xpNav = xpResDoc.CreateNavigator();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xpNav.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("g2", "http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_functions/MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result");

XPathNodeIterator xpNIter = xpNav.Select("//g2:R", nsmgr);

foreach (XPathNavigator nav in xpNIter)
{

    string r = 
        $"{nav.SelectSingleNode("./g2:D[1]", nsmgr).Value}," +
        $"{nav.SelectSingleNode("./g2:D[2]", nsmgr).Value}," +
        $"{nav.SelectSingleNode("./g2:D[3]", nsmgr).Value}," +
        $"{nav.SelectSingleNode("./g2:D[4]", nsmgr).Value}," +
        $"{nav.SelectSingleNode("./g2:D[5]", nsmgr).Value}," +
        $"{nav.SelectSingleNode("./g2:D[6]", nsmgr).Value}";

    Console.WriteLine(r);
}

// Start writing to a file stream;
```